# return to welcome menu

Tags: python, bots, py-telegram-bot-api

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def welcome(message):
    img = open('static/welcome5.gif', 'rb')
    bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img)

    # keyboard
    start = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("TEST1", callback_data='TEST1')


    start.row(item1)



    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "yo  ,{0.first_name}\n".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=start)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'TEST1':

                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, '
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                YOSEF3 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("test")
                YOSEF4 =types.InlineKeyboardButton("return", return " " ") *************

                markup.row(YOSEF3)
                markup.row(YOSEF4)



# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**[ i open from start keyboard inline buttons , to bot.callback more buttons and how i **return** from this to the start keyboard **

**[ i open from start keyboard inline buttons , to bot.callback more buttons and how i **return** from this to the start keyboard **